# generate array of object with json and ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use a js lib and I need to produce that json result with ASP .Net MVC :

```
[
  { "" : "--" },
  { "series-1" : "1 series" },
  { "series-3" : "3 series" },
  { "series-5" : "5 series" },
  { "series-6" : "6 series" },
  { "series-7" : "7 series" },
  { "selected" : "series-6" }
]
```

At this time that code :

```
var liste = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var site in sitesList)
{
    liste.Add(site.Id.ToString(), site.RaisonSociale);
}

return Json(liste,
  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

produce that JSON result :

```
{"-1":"Tous","93":"name"}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Regards

Comment: Well, where do those series key-value pairs coming from? It doesn't look like it matches those in your dictionary.

Comment: What is `sitesList`?

Comment: What are the values of Id and RaisonSociale of the elements of sitesList? If the values are the same that you want to be on the json result, convert the list to array and you should get what you want.

Comment: Yuval Itzchakov and Mr. Wolf : sitesList are issued from the database.

Comment: Bsa0 it is kind of key / value pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get it:

```
var liste = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
foreach(var site in sitesList)
{
    liste.Add(new Dictionary<string, string> { {site.Id.ToString(), site.RaisonSociale } } );
}

return Json(liste,
  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 2):

use JArray and JObject to produce your Custom Array

```
    JArray jArray = new JArray();

    foreach (var site in sitesList)
    {
      JObject jObject = new JObject();
      jObject.Add(site.Id.ToString(), site.RaisonSociale);
      jArray.Add(jObject);
    }
    return jArray;
```